# From an SSIS package how should I execute a sql script stored in a table as a varchar(max)?

Tags: sql, ssis

I'm storing large (`varchar(max)`) SQL scripts in a table. I'd like to execute the scripts in an SSIS package.

Looking at other posts on this site it's easy enough to get the `varchar(max)` into an object variable. But then what to do? Is there a way for an Execute Sql Task (SQLSourceType of Variable) to specify an Object variable rather than a String variable?

Is there an approach that will work?

Comment: You should be able to put your result into a String variable if you set the ResultSet property of your SQL Task to Single Row.

Comment: Jim, I did have my SQL Task set to Single Row. For some reason it wouldn't work with a varchar(max) column. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's how I might approach it:

1. Add a Data Flow task to your control flow

   - Add a Source (ADO.NET) that connects to your database
   - Create a Package level Object variable (for the next step)
   - Add a Recordset destination that populates your data into the Object variable created in the previous step
2. Back on the control flow:

   - Create a package level String variable for the "current" query (see next step)
   - Add a For Each ADO.NET enumerator

     - Connect the previous Data Flow task to the For Each task
     - Configure the For Each to use the Object variable as a source, and to store the column index with the SQL into the String variable
   - Add an Execute SQL task inside the For Each task

     - Configure it to execute a SQL Command from Variable, and pick the string variable containing the current query

Basically it will collect the queries from the table, then for each collected query, assign it to a variable, and then the Execute SQL command can pull the command text from that variable.